# Ubuntu on Virtual PC 2007 — cannot connect to the internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on Virtual PC 2007 on my desktop Windows machine. The internet connection has failed. Any tutorial on getting this working?

Answer (score 0):

In the Virtual PC settings for the Ubuntu VM, ensure the network adapter is set to 'bridged' or 'NAT' mode. If I remember correctly, bridged mode on VPC will just display the **name of your hardware network card** on the host instead of saying **bridged**. NAT will provide you internet connectivity through your host machine, while bridged will allow you to give your virtual machine it's own IP address on your LAN.

After setting it to one of these two modes, use NetworkManager in the top-right corner to confirm DHCP is operational and you have connectivity.

Comment: "use NetworkManager in the top-right corner to confirm DHCP is operational and you have connectivity." I didn't find that in Ubuntu. Where exactly is it located?

Comment: See image: http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/help/wireless/ubuntu1010-01-nm-hidden.png

Comment: I don't see that option in my network. All I have is:
Wired Network
  Auto etho
  Disconnect
  VPN Connections

Comment: I didn't mean the options, I meant the NetworkManager icon itself. If it says "Auto eth0" then it is configured for DHCP.

Comment: Right I clicked on the icon itself. And those are all choices I have. I connected to Auto etho but still cannot get online.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your VPC network settings?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Have to overide the http_proxy setting due to company network settings.